# Understanding the elements in groups(modulo, cyclic and other(?))

Tags: group-theory, number-theory, elementary-number-theory, finite-groups

Question exactly as given on past exam:

> Consider the group $G=(\mathbb{Z}/15\mathbb{Z})^\times$ (under multiplication). Let $H$ be the subgroup generated by $2$ (that is, $H = \langle 2 \rangle$). Write out the elements of $G,H$ and $G$/$H$. State $|G|,|H|$ and $[G:H]$

Now I want to list the elements of the following(With attempt underneath)

$$G = \{1_{15},2_{15},4_{15},7_{15},8_{15},11_{15},13_{15},14_{15}\}$$

With H, I don't know if it means that it is a subgroup of $G$ or of the integers. I will do my attempt at both
$$H_1 = 2_{15},4_{15},8_{15},1_{15}\;, \; H_2 = 2,4,8,16,32,...,2^n$$
Now based on the following question, $H_1$ makes more sense.
$$G/H = 7_{15},11_{15},13_{15},14_{15}$$
I think it is asking for cardinality
$$|G| = 8$$ 
$$|H| = 4$$

I don't even know what this one is:

$[G:H] = 4$

Comment: $|G|$ is not $15$. Most of the elements you wrote down aren't invertible mod 15... most obviously, 0 isn't. Check the definition of $(\mathbb Z/15\mathbb Z)^\times$ again. $[G:H]$ means the index of $H$ in $G$. For finite groups, we have that $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$.

Comment: @MikeMiller Oh silly me, I forgot to take into account the $^\times$

Comment: @MikeMiller If you have any time, could you review my edit per chance?

Comment: You forgot $4_{15}\in G$. In any case, it makes much more sense that $H_1\leq G$… but you never actually wrote the question you're trying to answer: what is it?

Comment: @EricStucky My question was essentially "Are the following correct", which they are now I believe. But yes, that was exactly how the $H$ part was phrased, so my guess is as good as yours. I imagine that $H_1$ was the correct answer.

Clarification on $[G:H] = |G|/|H|$, is this equal to cardinality of $G$ take away cardinality of $H$? OR is it equal to the cardinality of $G/H$?

Comment: The notation is very suggestive. $[G:H]$ is the cardinality of $G/H$, which is in turn the cardinality of $G$ divided by the cardinality of $H$.

Comment: @Ericstucky Doesn't $G/H$ read, "G without H"? $G$ divided $H$ here is $2$ not $4$?

Comment: The problem, though, is that it is hard to separate the setup from what we are supposed to be looking at. I hope it is not too rude to say it, but from my perspective, it looks like you're telling us this increasingly ridiculous story: "Consider this situation which I made up. I don't know what I mean by it, but I will try and interpret the notation I just wrote. Based on the following question (which I'm not telling you), I think I know what I meant. 'It' meant [this]. I also don't know what this new notation which I haven't used yet means. But I know it's 4."

Comment: Ah, no. $G\setminus H$ reads "$G$ without $H$". But $G/H$ is the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$. [If you saw it, please forgive my temper in the original edition of my last comment. Sometimes I type faster than I empathize :/ ]

Comment: @EricStucky Sorry, I see what you mean, the question I was given I will edit in. Also sorry I didn't realise $G/H$ and $G$ \ $H$ were distinct operators.

Comment: @Examin5days By the time you sent that, I'd been asleep. In general, don't worry too much about the time for a suggested edit to get reviewed; it's generally pretty quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I agree that $H$ should probably be a subgroup of $G$ rather than the integers, since the problem appears to be framed in terms of $G$. Your explicit sets for $G$ and $H$ look good, and the cardinalities are correct.

As you noted in the comments, you had some misunderstanding with the $/$ and $\setminus$ symbols. Here, $G/H$ refers to the set of cosets of $H$ in $G$. Therefore, each element of $G/H$ is a subset of $G$ with size $|H|$. Also, the notation $[G:H]$ is used to mean $|G/H|$, which is often more easily calculated as $|G|\,/\,|H|$; in this case it is $2$.

All that is left to do is to write $G/H$ down explicitly; have you seen this before?

Comment: I haven't seen this $G$ / $H$ before, and I have just read a few pages on it, yielding my attempt solution: Set 1 : $\{14_{15},13_{15},7_{15}\}$ set 2: $\{11_{15},7_{15},14_{15},13_{15}\}$. What do I call these two left cosets(instead of "set 1" and "set 2")(assuming they are even correct). OR should I just say $G$ / $H$ = etc

Thank you very much for your help so far!

Comment: Let's [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/15250/discussion-between-eric-stucky-and-exam-in-5-days).